# Pulling Down on ScrollView in SwiftUI Popover Closes It

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I know that there is a built-in behavior in modals in iOS that when you swipe them down, the modal pulls down and closes. But I'm running into an issue where the slightest downward scroll on a `ScrollView` in a `.popover` closes it instantly.

I'm using a `.popover` in this case because it's a popover in the Mac version of my app, but in iOS it defaults to a modal sheet.

Here's what is happening when I scroll down:

[image]

The instant I scroll down, the modal jitters and closes. Here's the sample project that illustrates that:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showModal = false
  var body: some View {
    ZStack{
      Button("Open Sheet"){
        showModal = true
      }
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $showModal, arrowEdge: .bottom){
      ModalView(showModal: $showModal)
    }
  }
}

struct ModalView: View{
  @Binding var showModal: Bool
  var body: some View{
    ScrollView{
      VStack{
        Text("One")
        Text("Two")
        Text("Three")
      }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .padding(20)
    .background(Color.gray)
  }
}
```

Is there something I can do to prevent the sheet/modal from closing when I scroll my `ScrollView` down?

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614539/12299030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SwiftUI bug. It has been fixed in Xcode 12.5 beta.